# mac os edit launchd.conf

Tags: macos, nano

### nano /etc/launchd.conf

setenv OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK /Users/kang/Desktop/OpenCV-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk
setenv EIGEN3_DIR /Users/kang/Desktop/OpenCV-android-sdk/eigen3

### echo $OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK $EIGEN3_DIR

then save and exit show that error

[ Error writing /etc/launchd.conf: Permission denied ]

Comment: The files in /etc belong to the system. You need to gain root privileges via `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf` and then enter your password for the root user account that you set up during setting up your machine (if you're the only one using the machine and have no other accounts, it should be the same your regular password).

You will need to elevate your privileges to the super user in order to modify that file since your regular account does not have sufficient access to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. above solution `sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf` worked for me.
2. Be careful with your EIGEN3_DIR path. Usually, it's not located inside of the OpenCV-android-sdk folder.

For example:

setenv OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK /Users/hy/Documents/GitHub/OpenCV-android-sdk
setenv EIGEN3_DIR Users/hy/Documents/GitHub/eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb